# Rewrite rule with hyphen

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^/Recent-* /mydir/recent$1 [NC,I,R=301]
```

Now I want my URL(Recent-Name.xml) to redirect but not (Recent.xml)

The above rule redirects both. Any idea how to prevent recent.xml from redirecting?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/Recent\-+$ /mydir/recent$1 [NC,I,R=301]`

Comment: @Ejay that regex will not match `Recent-Name.xml`

Comment: yes, was unsure about it myself but wanted him to give it a try. thanks for pointing out :D **Edit** could you please elaborate why it wouldn't?

Comment: @Ejay Because of the `$` (end of string), the `Recent\-+$` regex will match `Recent-` and `Recent------------`, but not `Recent-anything`

Comment: ah, thanks again :) I missed a `.` there? `^/Recent\-.+$` that's ok, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` regex modifier means "none or more" of the character preceding it. Which means there could be *no* hyphens and it will match. Just get rid of the `*` or make it so it matches letters:

```
RewriteRule ^/Recent-[A-Za-z]*\.xml$ /mydir/recent [NC,I,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon what if I want to make it independent of the file extension?

Comment: @Mithil  Just remove the `\.xml$` then.

Comment: Well this is what is happening    

RewriteRule ^/Recent-[A-Za-z]*$ /mydir/recent$1 [NC,I,R=301]  

recent-test.aspx gives a 404 while earlier it used to redirect properly.

Comment: @Mithil you don't want the `$` at the end of your regex (you want to remove it like I said in my other comment)

Comment: One last thing, recent.aspx does not redirect(which is what I want) but recent.xml does. Why?

Comment: @Mithil are you sure your browser isn't caching the redirect? If it's 301 the browser will cache it since it means it's a *permanent* redirect.

Comment: Exactly what it was. @Jon appreciate your help. Saved my day.